# How to disable silverlight (when creating sites) in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom site template in SharePoint 2010. It works well when there's no silverlight installed on machine. When there's silverlight on machine, after fill in the information for creating a sharepoint site and click ok it gives error without any explanation.

Since there will be many editors I can't ask them to uninstall silverlight on all their machines. How to fix this, for me even using javascript to disable silverlight is ok. but how?

Thanks.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: "An unhandled exception occurred in the Silverlight application"

Answer (score 1):

To disable Silverlight, (For IE 7, at least...)

Go to 
Tools...Internet Options...Programs tab, 
Manage Add-Ons, find "Microsoft Silverlight", 
click "Disable", and click OK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have many part time editors therefore I can't ask everyone to disable Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Just so this has an answer -

This error is common when security validation is disabled for a web application.

In Central Administration access the General Settings for the Web Application and scroll down to find Web Page Security Validation and turn this on.